# Retraction and the k-fold projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $k > 2$. Is there an embedding of $S^1$ in $\#_k \mathbb{RP}^2$ such that $S^1$ is a retract of $\#_k \mathbb{RP}^2$?

I know that this is not correct when $k=1$ (homotopy argument), and this is correct when $k=2$.

But I have no idea in the case that $k>2$.
Thanks.

Comment: What is a $k$-fold projective plane?

Comment: I mean k RP2's glued to each other

Comment: this is a 2-manifold. for example Klein bottle is homeomorphic to 2RP2

Comment: Glued to each other *how*? (and please ad this information to the body of the question itself)

Comment: @mandegar There are lots of ways to glue two $\mathbb{RP}^2$'s together.  In this case, you are talking about the connected sum.  So $k\mathbb{RP}^2:=\mathbb{RP}^2\#\cdots\#\mathbb{RP}^2$ $k$ times.

Comment: yes, exactly. thanks